# ViewExpiredException on liberty

Tags: session, jsf, websphere-liberty

I have the application running fine on websphere 8.5.10 with JSF 2.1. Now we are switching to JSF 2.2 and liberty 17. And start getting the  ViewExpiredException when load the second page.

I have the below in web.xml

```
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>`
```

Changing to client helped a little bit, but getting other errors.

If the value is server, what's the name of the session cookie that JSF is using to retrieve the session information?

Comment: Are you totally clearing your browser caches before testing the new version?

Comment: Yes. I used the incognito mode.